# Tilt and turn door brushes against the reveal

Tags: doors

My door is getting a little old, 10 years, and the side of the door began to brush against the reveal (around the upper half). Searching a bit a came to the conclusion that I have to adjust the screw on the picture: [image]

I tried clockwise (not sure whether this is the way turn in order to bring the door towards the hinge), initially it moved hard, but after it became easy. Now I can easily twist the screw in both direction. But I can twist in both direction 5-10 turns, nothing happens, the brushing problem remains.

So I do not know, whether I am twisting the proper screw, and why is it moving so easy. Maybe it got broken?

Please help me how can I adjust the door.

Answer (score 1):

After you've turned the adjuster more than a small number of times, consider to grasp firmly the door and attempt to move it up and down. If there is paint or rust on the moving parts, they may have become bonded and require outside force (you) to move in the manner desired.